# R: Compare each element to all elements

Tags: r

I have two vectors and I want to compare each element in one vector to all the elements in the second vector.
Example

```
> a = seq(0,4, 1)
> a
[1] 0 1 2 3 4
> b = c(1,2,3,4,5)
> b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

For each element in "b" I want to count the number of elements in "a" that are smaller than the respective element in "b". The correct answer should be

```
1, 2,3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
colSums(sapply(b, `>`, a))
```

---

Or with `outer`

```
colSums(outer(b, a, `>`))
```

---

Or possibly with `findInterval`

```
findInterval(b, a, left.open = TRUE)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```